# HTML: "send to a friend" link

Tags: html, email, mailto

I need to add a "Send to a friend" link to my website.

When a user clicks on it, their e-mail software should open and the e-mail should be already filled.

Subject: Website Name
Body: Link to website, short description

is that possible ?
thanks

Comment: http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<a href="mailto:enteryour@addresshere.com?subject=Website Name&body=Link to website, short description">Send me an email</a>
```

Is one way.

Comment: uhm, why is my Safari visiting a new page instead of sending an email ? And Firefox just not doing anything ? I've just copied pasted your code. thanks

Comment: Is this actually / still a problem?

Comment: From what I know, mailto shouldn't pose a problem in these browsers. Perhaps certain plug-/add-ins are causing the problem? And you could try Luc's comment (or sending something without spaces).

Answer (score 2):

Using protocol mailto and GET parameters is correct, but you also have to use the urlencoded version for strings:

```
<a href="mailto:enteryour@addresshere.com?subject=Website+Name&body=Link+to+website%2C+short+description">Send me an email</a>
```

Spaces become "+" or "%20". PHP provides function urlencode() for this, python 2.x urllib.urlencode() of the urllib module, Perl has uri_escape of the URI::Escape package ... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="mailto:myfriend@gmail.com?subject=Patrick's Website at patrickrules.com&body=<a href="http://www.patrickrules.com&quot; title="Link to Patrick's Official Website">It's Patrick's Official Website!</a>">Send to a friend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="mailto:s123@example.com?subject=Feedback for 
webdevelopersnotes.com&body=Link to website, short description">Send to a friend</a>
```

Comment: Your Google-Fu is as strong as mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="mailto:..." />`.

[Reference](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/mailto.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are going to need a simple form to allow people to enter there friends email address. php mail perhaps (just in case people don't have a email program).